# How to hide HTML element containing only spaces using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML :

```
<div id="rightCon">




                    </div>
```

And then I have the following script at the top :

```
$('#rightCon:empty').hide();
```

Why is the div not hiding? I can see that there is some spaces(that I can´t get ridoff) but does that really matter? How do I remove/hide this div when its empty with only spaces?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding an element that contains only spaces using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380906/hiding-an-element-that-contains-only-spaces-using-css)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solved the problem.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                if($('#rightCon').text().trim().length < 1)
                {$('#rightCon').hide();}
            });
```

Comment: Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 7):

Your element appears to have a bunch of white space, which will give it a text node. It won't be matched by `:empty` for that reason.

You could try finding the element and checking it's contents explicitly:

```
$('#rightCon').filter(function() {
  var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s*/g, '');
  return !text;
}).hide();
```

Comment: It will only hide the element if the `.filter()` function thinks that the element contains nothing but white space.

Comment: @SnowJim oops sorry; the regex needs a "g" - updating answer

Comment: @Lucio yes I just figured that out :)  Thanks!!

Comment: @SnowJim You should mark this answer as *accepted*. [It is working](http://jsfiddle.net/aQ4qH/)

Comment: @Pointy, the original answer was only incorrect in that it had `!!` in the return statement instead of `!`.  The `g` in the regex is not necessary.

I assume there is no special jQuery selector to match an element which has only whitespace content in text nodes.

Comment: @Jake  not as a selector. Excluding such effectively empty elements is what the code above does.

Answer (score 0):

Your div is not actually `empty` (It contains whitespace). So the selector `$("#rightCon:empty")` will never evaluate and hide the `div`.

Since `HTML` elements should be unique, you can safely assume that you can select the correct element via:

```
var rightCon = $("#rightCon");
```

You can then hide the element via:

```
right.hide();
```

Or

```
 $("#rightCon").hide();
```

Comment: Yes, but that means it will always be hidden, I need it to only be hidden when it got whitespaces.

Comment: That will hide the element whether it has stuff in it or not.

Comment: You should use Regular Expressions.

Comment: Damn didnt know the pseudo selector existed

Comment: @SnowJim - you can use a regular expression or use `val` to see if the div contains any content.