# CSS :empty pseudo-selector combined with :after pseudo-element

Tags: reactjs, css, styled-components

I'm looking for a way to add a `:content` pseudo-element to an empty element and ran into the `:empty` CSS pseudo-selector which looks like it would serve the purpose I'm looking for. Basically, I want to add a generic message like "Nothing found" `:after` an empty element like a list.

For whatever reason my attempts to style empty elements aren't working, here's an example:
https://codepen.io/kylegill/pen/ZVLEBg

This is the Markup/HTML:

```
<ul class="list">
</ul>
<!-- ^ Not getting selected by :empty:after  -->
<ul class="list">
  <li>This list is not empty.</li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS:

```
.list:empty:after {
  content: "Nothing found";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found [this article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/e/empty/) that helped answer my question.

The `:empty` class has some weird behavior and won't select elements with a space or a return/line break in them.

Ex: `<div> </div>` won't be selected, but `<div></div>` will.

The CSS4 spec includes `:blank` in this use case, which will select elements with whitespace, where `:empty` will not.

Here's an updated example:

https://codepen.io/kylegill/pen/vvgYZe

Comment: because a space has a meaning in CSS oryouwillhaveapainreadingthis ;) so this is not weird but bydesign

Comment: a space is interpreted as a 'text node', and empty text node, you can see it in the browser inspector

Comment: makes sense! Something I'm glad I'll be looking for moving forward!

Comment: Here is one more input: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380906/hiding-an-element-that-contains-only-spaces-using-css

Answer (score 0):

As @kylegill pointed out, the `:empty` selector does not work if there's a space and `:blank` is not implemented yet.

However, there is a workaround for browsers that support the `:has` selector (https://caniuse.com/?search=has).

```
div:not(:has(*))::before {
  content: 'This div has no child elements';
}
```

It will select all `div` elements that don't have any child elements.